# using function in lapply in data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

If there is a sample data set as below.

```
> tmp <- data.table(x=c(1:10),y=(5:14))
> tmp
     x  y
 1:  1  5
 2:  2  6
 3:  3  7
 4:  4  8
 5:  5  9
 6:  6 10
 7:  7 11
 8:  8 12
 9:  9 13
10: 10 14
```

I want choose two lowest number and I want change 0 value to the other numbers.

like

```
   x y
 1: 1 5
 2: 2 6
 3: 0 0
 4: 0 0
 5: 0 0
 6: 0 0
 7: 0 0
 8: 0 0
 9: 0 0
10: 0 0
```

I think the coding is

```
tmp[, c("x","y"):=lapply(.SD, x[which(!x %in% sort(x)[1:2])] = 0}), .SDcols=c("x","y")]
```

but it changes all 0

How can i solve this problem.

Comment: What if the numbers are not unique? Ie. suppose you have `>2` 1s in the first column, in that case, do you want to get the `first` two 1s?

Comment: IIUC you'd like to replace all but the lowest 2 values for *each column* to 0. I'd accomplish this with for-loop over the columns, and using `sort.int` along with argument `partial` to find the nth smallest for each column and replacing all other rows to 0 for that column. But we can do it more efficiently by implementing linear time algorithms to find nth max (which is [FR#919](http://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/919), yet to be done).

Answer (score 4):

To expand on my comment, I'd do something like this:

```
for (j in names(tmp)) {
    col = tmp[[j]]
    min_2 = sort.int(unique(col), partial=2L)[2L] # 2nd lowest value
    set(tmp, i = which(col > min_2), j = j, value = 0L)
}
```

This loops over all the columns in `tmp`, and gets the 2nd minimum value for each column using `sort.int` with `partial` argument, which is slightly more efficient than using `sort` (as we don't have to sort the entire data set to find the 2nd minimum value).

Then we use `set()` to replace those rows where the column value is greater than the 2nd minimum value, for *that* column, with the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try

```
tmp[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x,
             !rank(x, ties.method='first') %in% 1:2, 0))]
#   x y
#1: 1 5
#2: 2 6
#3: 0 0
#4: 0 0
#5: 0 0
#6: 0 0
#7: 0 0
#8: 0 0
#9: 0 0
#10:0 0
```